# To Replace a characters after tab in a file

Tags: sed, text-formatting

```
Smith,Terry    7-1234
StClair,pat    2-3456
Adams,fram     5-5972
Brown,Robin    4-5587
Benson,Sam     1-3662
Stair,Chris    4-6122
```

I want to replace the first two characters of the phone number with X using  `sed`, and to delete the  all  the first name in the table.

Comment: Which ones are the first names? Is it the first name or the second?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed 's/,.*-/,X/' file
Smith,X1234
StClair,X3456
Adams,X5972
Brown,X5587
Benson,X3662
Stair,X6122
```

This simply replaces anything between the first comma and the last dash on the line with the string `,X`.

Comment: thanks it working