# unix command to merge same coloums and take the average

Tags: linux

Can anyone help me out to solve this i have started learning Unix recently

```
name     class  physics chemistry   maths   
mayank   xi      55        89        38 
bhawna   xi      56        65        85 
ashish   xi      69        96        69 
ashankar xii     84        86        97 
ankush   xi      87        68        85 
meghna   xi      69        78        84 
chaitra  xi      63        87        48 
pavithra xii     72        48        59 
akshat   xii     87        84        67 
somesh   xii     88        82        57
```

consider the above data is a tab delimited file. You have to prepare 3 reports as a tab delimited file from the data provided

```
classwise_data.txt
class_xii.txt
class_xi.txt
```

Your script should generate these three tab delimited files as the name given (with space )  and should have data as given on the right.

```
classwise data.txt  

class   no of students  phy avg     che avg   maths avg 
xi        6             66.5         80.5     68.16667  
Xii       4             82.75        75        70
```

```
class xii.txt

name         class  physics chemistry   maths   avg
ashankar       xii  84         86        97     89
pavithra       xii  72         48        59     59.66666667
akshat         xii  87         84        67     79.33333333
somesh         xii  88         82        57     75.66666667
```

```
class xi.txt

name    class   physics chemistry   maths   avg
mayank  xi       55         89       38     60.66666667
bhawna  xi       56         65       85     68.66666667
ashish  xi       69         96       69     78
ankush  xi       87         68       85     80
meghna  xi       69         78       84     77
chaitra xi       63         87       48     66
```

Comment: someone here will help you with your work ... please add your work to your post and explain what problem you are having and include a question that you wish to ask

Comment: i did it already

Comment: I change tag, this hardly relate to unix socket.

Comment: i see no code that you wrote ... i see no question being asked ... i see no description of the difficulty that you are having

Comment: @Star_Dust : What have you tried so far ? This, and your earlier question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559391/to-replace-a-characters-after-tab-in-a-file would benefit from some details of what you've had a try at, or what ideas you have.  Hoping you are not just looking for homework-as-a-service.......

Comment: @steve tried it by using awk command with if condition.

Comment: @Star_Dust that's a good tool to be using for this problem.  And welcome to U&L.  People are usually more responsive to questions like yours if the person posting it has provided some example input, example output *and* some details of what they've tried so far.  So I'd recommend you revising the question to include your `awk` attempt.

Comment: @steve if have done the 2 and 3 table can u help me out with the first one how to merge the colums with same field and taking the average.....thanks